# Getting location information of the connected USB device

Tags: windows, powershell

what is the powershell command to read the following registry entry?

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_03A8&PID_0258\6&af75239&0&3\LocationInformation
```

I tried the following code, i used to get the Device information only

```
gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} |
Sort Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID |
Ft -GroupBy Manufacturer DeviceID
```

how to get the location information of the connected usb device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for that :

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_03F0&PID_1F1D\5&3aded796&0&2' -Name LocationInformation


PSPath              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_03F0&PID_1F1D\5&3aded796&0&2
PSParentPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_03F0&PID_1F1D
PSChildName         : 5&3aded796&0&2
PSDrive             : HKLM
PSProvider          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
LocationInformation : Port_#0002.Hub_#0004
```

Or

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_03F0&PID_1F1D\5&3aded796&0&2' -Name LocationInformation).LocationInformation
Port_#0002.Hub_#0004
```

---

You can get the connected devices using :

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_USBHub
```

---

You just need to join the two results for exemple for my hard drive :

```
$PnpdeviceId = (gwmi win32_USBHub | where { $_.name -like '*stockage*'}).PNPDeviceID
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$PnpdeviceId" -Name LocationInformation).LocationInformation
```

Comment: If we run the following command, gives the result for the Device ID of the connected USB Device.                                                    'gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} |
Sort Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID |
Ft -GroupBy Manufacturer DeviceID'                                      How to get the location information (Port_#0002.Hub_#0004) for the connected USB device? @JPBlanc

Comment: What is the command to get the location information (Port_#0002.Hub_#0004) for the currently connected USB device? @JPBlanc

Comment: @Sathiya, I Edit my answer using Win32_USBHub allow you to get the connected devices.

Comment: 'Get-WmiObject Win32_USBHub' command used to get the information of the connected usb device, except the location information(Port_#0002.Hub_#0004) of the device.Default Device Id contains the port number of the device.how to find the connected Hub number of usb device? @JPBlanc

Answer (score 3):

Look at `Get-ItemProperty` Cmdlet with registry Provider Path.

For example,

```
Get-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell
```

Try this for getting location information for all USB devices:

```
$devid = gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Select -ExpandProperty DeviceID
$devid | % { Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$_" -Name LocationInformation -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
```

Comment: What is the command to get the location information (Port_#0002.Hub_#0004) for the currently connected USB device? @ravikanth