# From Win32_PnPSignedDriver

Tags: c#, usb

I am working on a C#/WPF project in which I need to detect the port number when a USB Masee Storage device is removed or inserted.  However I need the Port Location.

For example `Win32_PnPSignedDriver` has the property `Location` which will return something like `Port_#0003.Hub_#0003`.

This is exactly what I need,  however, this will not populate when the drive is removed or inserted.  I have searched all the Win32 API and I cannot find a way to get the actual Port/Hub values from the "Location information" other than this.  Can anyone be of any assistance?

Comment: So you want we write an entire code file for him/her? We ought to give him/her advice not ready-to-be-compiled solutions.

Comment: I think his question is clear, although I don't know the answer. Do you? He has already told us that he's tried a property on `Win32_PnPSignedDriver` but it is not updated. You could answer this with a link to the documentation ... or you could ask him to repeat what he's tried...

Comment: I'm not going to do it for you, but you will need to use the `ManagementObjectSearcher` and write some queries.  It has been done in powershell [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874882/getting-location-information-of-the-connected-usb-device).  Check out wmiexplorer tool, that could be of use too.

Comment: You should add more details.  Do you know all the USB device information?  Do you know the vendor ID and Product ID?  Is it always the same?  Turns out I would actually answer this question if I knew your situation.